# Pre-processing Nodejs script with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have created a nodejs script which access the DOM of html file and get an element by id. Now i need to generate a Javascript file equivalent to my nodejs script (like do browserify) so i can integrate it in my javascript program.

So  i'm searching any solution to integrate my nodejs script in javascript program

Comment: i don't think that DOM is available at node server

Comment: @jai yes i require phantom to be able to access the DOM

Comment: btw , why arent you using browserify ?

Comment: @saru95 because i don't need that my javascript code can be excuted from browser, i just want to integrate my js code ino other javascript program.

Comment: @jai what is the other possibilities to access DOM other than nodejs

Comment: @ameni look this up https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom

Comment: @saru95 i have to  access the dom and get an element by id like i do with nodejs but without using nodejs :

Comment: var phantom = require('phantom');
var sUrl = 'editor1.html';
phantom.create(function(ph) {
 ph.createPage(function(page) {
  page.open(sUrl, function(status) {
   console.log("opened diagram? ", status);
   page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById("GraphImage").src;
   }, function(result) {
    console.log(result)
    ph.exit();
   });
  });
 });
}, {
 dnodeOpts : {
  weak : false
 }
});

Comment: @ameni javascript runs just in browser . If you dont want to run it there, node.js is your only option . period .

Comment: @saru95 yes but when i do browserify to my nodejs script and i test it from browser i'm getting error http.createServer is not a function (because of phantom)

Comment: This is what you are looking for . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053156/browserify-error-http-createserver-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't use any Node.js-specific APIs, a simple ES6 to ES5 transpiler should do the job. In that case checkout [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

#### Babel quick usage guide:

```
npm install -g babel babel-preset-es2015

babel --presets es2015 YOUR_JS_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE
```

If you do make use of `require` calls and other Node.js shenanigans, then checkout [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) which is more involved but will do what you want and bundle up any node modules you're using.

#### Browserify quick usage guide:

```
npm install -g browserify
browserify YOUR_JS_FILE -o OUTPUT_FILE
```

Comment: please give me more details :)

Comment: @ameni Added quick usage infos

Comment: this command "babel --presets es2015 YOUR_JS_FILE" will generate a js file equivalent to my nodejs script ?

Comment: It will convert ES6 code to ES5 which is what most browsers support.

Comment: what i'm tying to do is to generate a javascript code which can be compiled and executed in javascript program not from browser

Comment: Ok check Browserify then.

Comment: @ameni Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: i'm getting with browserify javascript code which can be executed from browser but i just want to get javascript code which i can integrate in my javascript program

Comment: Then you will have to make the conversion manually. Try to just copy paste your Node.js script in your browser app and correct the eventual errors you get one after the other.