# Is it possible to create a local javascript proxy in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, server, proxy, streaming

I have a video player in my html page:

```
<video width="720" height="405" controls poster="http://www.supportduweb.com/page/media/videoTag/BigBuckBunny.png">
    <source src="localhost:3000/video?id=videoId" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video. <a href="http://www.supportduweb.com/">http://www.supportduweb.com/</a>-->
</video>
```

The url is pointing to a local proxy that has been spawned by [express](https://expressjs.com/fr/). The proxy is in charge to pipe the response from another server after having the data decrypted.

It actually works perfectly in my electron application. The problem is that now, I need this to work in a browser. I can't find a way to spawn my proxy in the browser.

Is there another way to point from the streaming media to a kind of proxy, to be able to treat the request and return a custom response piped as the http response?

the following schema explains maybe more explicitly the problem: [Descriptive schema of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRBD3.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is this package call axios, which is very good and mature. With it you can specify a base url which can be different domain than one your client is running at. Also it is possible to create your own proxy. I would put examples, but their documentation. Is well explained and also is very easy to use. Just look up for axios, download the module or link the dns

```
  // You can also define your proxy using the conventional `http_proxy` and
  // `https_proxy` environment variables. If you are using environment variables
  // for your proxy configuration, you can also define a `no_proxy` environment
  // variable as a comma-separated list of domains that should not be proxied.
  // Use `false` to disable proxies, ignoring environment variables.
  // `auth` indicates that HTTP Basic auth should be used to connect to the proxy, and
  // supplies credentials.
  // This will set an `Proxy-Authorization` header, overwriting any existing
  // `Proxy-Authorization` custom headers you have set using `headers`.
  proxy: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9000,
    auth: {
      username: 'mikeymike',
      password: 'rapunz3l'
    }
  },
```

https://www.github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this package but I'll try again for sure and be right back to you!

Comment: The problem is that I can't run a node server. The objectif is to be serverless (the server I'm talking about is a p2p library). So I won't be able to use this package unfortunately...

Comment: But can add a dns link on your index.html <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

Comment: So the answer is no. There's a good explanation from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053156/browserify-error-http-createserver-is-not-a-function)